# How to enforce https in <form action>?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, https

I've created a form in wordpress for a hotel booking and redirected to the third-party booking engine. This code works fine when run on localhost but when I move it to real host the code doesn't work.

The problem I face is in the code I clearly indicate "https://" but when I submit the form it doesn't run "https://" which make the booking engine load fail. It just load "secure.guestcentric.net/api/bg/book.php.." (lack https://).

```html
<form action="https://secure.guestcentric.net/api/bg/book.php" target="_blank" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="apikey" id="APIlang" value="ac70e6647f5cea6fe9ecb4be3ea86fe9">
  <div class="fields_wrap">
    <h3>'.$title.'</h3>
    <div class="row_field field_text">
      <label class="label_title">'.__('Check In','tfuse').'</label>
      <input type="text" name="startDay" value="" id="check_in">
      <span class="icon icon-calendar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row_field field_select">
      <label class="label_title">'.__('Number of Nights','tfuse').'</label>
      <select name="nrNights" class="select_styled" style="width:225px">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="12">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="row_field input_styled">
    </div>
    <div class="row_divider"></div>
    <div class="row_field field_text">
      <label class="label_title"><strong>'.__('Promotion Code','tfuse').':</strong>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="pc" value="" id="promocode">
      <span class="icon icon-asterisk"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_field rowSubmit">
    <button type="submit" id="room_search_submit">
      <span class="icon-stack">
                                    <i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i>
                                    <i class="icon-search"></i></span> '.$search.'
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have an .htaccess related issue, check the Rewrite conditions in your .htaccess file.

Comment: Could you open the URL in browser using DevTools (like FireBug) and check for the Net/Requests/etc tab? I opened the URL and it was fine, response code of 200 (thus no redirects from the server side). Have you checked your local configuration?